# Boxplot for 50 States over time

Tags: r, variables, graph, boxplot, usmap

*Edited based on answers*

I have data on marriage rates for the 50 states over time. I am trying to make individual box plots for each state and be able to also put these plots on a map of the states in R. If that is not possible, due to congestion, I would love to know how to place just the min or max values for each state on a map. 
[Link to Data if interested](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qbmstduHWXNMknPMTIb_tFNEKRB6PAm-/view?usp=sharing)

I had my data listed in R two ways the first way I thought would be better in terms of graphing.

```
 marriage<-read.csv(file="~/Desktop/masters.csv", header=T, sep=",",check.names=FALSE)
 marriagefine <-
        marriage %>%
        pivot_longer(
          cols = `2017`:`1990`,
          names_to = 'year',
          values_to = 'rate'
        ) %>%
        mutate(
          year = as.numeric(year)
        )
```

Which gets R to read my table something like this;

```
> marriagefine
# A tibble: 1,071 x 3
  State    year  rate
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Alabama  2017   7  
2 Alabama  2016   7.1
3 Alabama  2015   7.4
4 Alabama  2014   7.8
5 Alabama  2013   7.8
6 Alabama  2012   8.2
7 Alabama  2011   8.4
8 Alabama  2010   8.2
9 Alabama  2009   8.3
10 Alabama  2008   8.6
# … with 1,061 more rows
```

The other way to read it

```
                  State 2017 2016 2015 2014 2013 2012 2011 2010 2009 2008 2007 2006 2005 2004 2003 2002 2001 2000 1999 1995 1990
1               Alabama  7.0  7.1  7.4  7.8  7.8  8.2  8.4  8.2  8.3  8.6  8.9  9.2  9.2  9.4  9.6  9.9  9.4 10.1 10.8  9.8 10.6
2                Alaska  6.9  7.1  7.4  7.5  7.3  7.2  7.8  8.0  7.8  8.4  8.5  8.2  8.2  8.5  8.1  8.3  8.1  8.9  8.6  9.0 10.2
3               Arizona  5.8  5.9  5.9  5.8  5.4  5.6  5.7  5.9  5.6  6.0  6.4  6.5  6.6  6.7  6.5  6.7  7.6  7.5  8.2  8.8 10.0
4              Arkansas  9.5  9.9 10.0 10.1  9.8 10.9 10.4 10.8 10.7 10.6 12.0 12.4 12.9 13.4 13.4 14.3 14.3 15.4 14.8 14.4 15.3
5           California   6.3  6.5  6.2  6.4  6.5  6.0  5.8  5.8  5.8  6.7  6.2  6.3  6.4  6.4  6.1  6.2  6.5  5.8  6.4  6.3  7.9
6              Colorado  7.3  7.4  6.8  7.1  6.5  6.8  7.0  6.9  6.9  7.4  7.1  7.2  7.6  7.4  7.8    8  8.2  8.3  8.2  9.0  9.8
7           Connecticut  5.6  5.6  5.3  5.4    5  5.2  5.5  5.6  5.9  5.4  5.5  5.5  5.8  5.8  5.5  5.7  5.4  5.7  5.8  6.6  7.9
8              Delaware  5.5  5.6  5.7    6  6.6  5.8  5.2  5.2  5.4  5.5  5.7  5.9  5.9  6.1    6  6.4  6.5  6.5  6.7  7.3  8.4
9  District of Columbia  8.2  8.1  8.2 11.8 10.8  8.4  8.7  7.6  4.7  4.1  4.2    4  4.1  5.2  5.1  5.1  6.2  4.9  6.6  6.1  8.2
10              Florida  7.8  8.1  8.2  7.3    7  7.2  7.4  7.3  7.5  8.0  8.5  8.6  8.9  9.0    9  9.4  9.3  8.9  8.7  9.9 10.9
11              Georgia  6.9  6.8  6.2  ---  ---  6.5  6.6  7.3  6.6  6.0  6.8  7.3  7.0  7.9    7  6.5  6.1  6.8  7.8  8.4 10.3
12               Hawaii 15.3 15.6 15.9 17.7 16.3 17.5 17.6 17.6 17.2 19.1 20.8 21.9 22.6 22.6   22 20.8 19.6 20.6 18.9 15.7 16.4
13                Idaho  7.8  8.1  8.2  8.4  8.2  8.2  8.6  8.8  8.9  9.5 10.0 10.1 10.5 10.8 10.9   11 11.2 10.8 12.1 13.1 13.9
```

My box plot command based on answers listed below

```
boxplot(rate ~ State, data = marriagefine, 
         main="Box Plot for Marriage Rates by State", 
         xlab="States", ylab="Rates",              
         col=rainbow(length(unique(marriagefine$State))))
```

How would I overlay each box plot and or minimum/maximum values for each plot onto the us map? I know this is the basic outline.

```
library(usmap)
plot_usmap(regions = c("states", "state", "counties", "county"),
include = c(), exclude = c(), data = data.frame(),
values = "values", labels = FALSE,
label_color = "black")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a shiny solution:

```
lapply(c("shiny", "data.table", "ggplot2", "RColorBrewer", "ggrepel"),
    require, character.only = TRUE)

# mangle data
marriage <- fread("masters.csv", header = TRUE)
marriage <- melt(marriage, id.vars = "State")
marriage$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(marriage$variable ))
setnames(marriage, c("State", "year", "rate"))
marriage$State <- tolower(marriage$State)
states_map <- map_data("state")
marriage <- merge(data.table(data.frame(state.center), 
    state.abb, State=tolower(state.name)), marriage, by="State")

# pick fixed color palette
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))
sc <- scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100), 
    limits = range(marriage$rate))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Marriage"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("year", "Year", min(marriage$year), 
                max(marriage$year), value=min(marriage$year), step = 1)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "box", height = "800px")
        )
    )
)

# Define server function
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$box <- renderPlot({
        req(input$year)
        DT <- marriage[year==input$year]
        ggplot(DT, aes(map_id = State)) +
            geom_map(aes(fill = rate), map = states_map) +
            expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
            sc +
            geom_text_repel(data=DT, aes(x=x, y=y, label = rate), size=10)
    })
}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In reply to the request: A static version with two plots with the maxima and minima for each state next to each other:

```
# Load packages
lapply(c("data.table", "ggplot2", "RColorBrewer", "ggrepel", "cowplot"),
    require, character.only = TRUE)

# mangle data
marriage <- fread("masters.csv", header = TRUE)
marriage <- melt(marriage, id.vars = "State")
marriage$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(marriage$variable ))
setnames(marriage, c("State", "year", "rate"))
marriage$State <- tolower(marriage$State)
states_map <- map_data("state")
marriage <- merge(data.table(data.frame(state.center), 
    state.abb, State=tolower(state.name)), marriage, by = "State")

# pick fixed color palette
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))
sc <- scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100), 
    limits = range(marriage$rate))

# sort by State and rate
setkeyv(marriage, c("State", "rate"))

# pick year with largest and smallest rate (could be one of several)
DT.max <- marriage[, tail(.SD, 1), by = State]
DT.min <- marriage[, head(.SD, 1), by = State]

theme_set(theme_void())
# generate plot of maximum and minimum rates by State
p1 <- ggplot(DT.max, aes(map_id = State)) +
    geom_map(aes(fill = rate), map = states_map) +
    expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
    sc + 
    geom_text_repel(data=DT.max, aes(x=x, y=y, 
        label = paste0(rate, "\n(",year,")")), size=3.5) +
    ggtitle("Maximum marriage rate 1990-2017 \nby State (year measured)") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p2 <- ggplot(DT.min, aes(map_id = State)) +
    geom_map(aes(fill = rate), map = states_map) +
    expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
    sc + 
    geom_text_repel(data=DT.min, aes(x=x, y=y, 
        label = paste0(rate, "\n(",year,")")), size=3.5) +
    ggtitle("Minimum marriage rate 1990-2017 \nby State (year measured)") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

# plot plots next to each other
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

Comment: Wow this is so intricate! I did not know R could do this. Is there a way I can change your code, or just start a new code if creating a shiny object wouldn't work for this, to get just two maps one that states all the max values for each state and its associated year and the same for the minimum value on the US Map? For example over Nevada it would say 99 and 1990.

Answer (score 2):

Error should be straightforward as there is no such object in your global environment. Specifically, there is no assignment of *State* as a standalone object with an element named *rate* to be able to call `State$rate`. Instead, you have two fields in a data frame named *State* and *rate* where separately you can call: `marriagefine$State` and `marriagefine$rate`.

However, `boxplot` support formula style which runs according to items data frame passed in *data* argument. (Below only uses the posted data in body of post)

```
# BY YEAR
boxplot(rate ~ year, data = marriagefine, 
        main="Stats for Marriage Rates, 1990-2017", 
        xlab="States", ylab="Rates", 
        col=rainbow(length(2017:1990)))
```

[image: Boxplot by Year]

```
# BY STATE
boxplot(rate ~ State, data = marriagefine, 
        main="Stats for Marriage Rates, 1990-2017", 
        xlab="States", ylab="Rates",  
        col=rainbow(length(unique(marriagefine$State))))
```

[image: BoxPlot by State]

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/XORK99064)</kbd>

Comment: What is the "marriage_long" doing? When I run that it shows that object is not found, but it seems to run fine when I replaced it with "marriagefine"

Comment: That is the name of my data frame version per the demo which you can run to output same graphs.